# Firefox in Visual Studio 2012 Webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, firefox, visual-studio-2012, browser

I am looking for Mozilla ActiveX Control for **Visual Studio 2012 Webbrowser**;
All VB.Net/Visual Studio forums lead to the same website which is: http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm
However, this might work for older VB.Net versions but it is not working for me in Visual Studio **2012**;
Is there an equivalent version of Mozilla ActiveX Control for **Visual Studio 2012 Webbrowser**?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 3rd party tools for doing this :

Check this link : http://thebot.net/threads/vb-net-how-to-make-a-firefox-webbrowser.142359/

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.